# How to handle shared data in async process environment? (Node.js)

Tags: data-structures, asynchronous, node.js

You have a Node.js server running, accepting connections from the outside (via Socket.io, but it's irrelevant). Every time a connection is made, you create an "Instance" structure, and then copy the instance inside a global Instances array. This part is asynchronous.

Every three instances created, you'll hand them all to another process and flag them as "promoted" (or delete them, or something else, you get the idea).

The problem is that it will go all well if the connections would arrive in a discrete laps of time, say 100ms one after the other. If they arrive almost at the same time it is quite possible that you'll end up having the famous three instances in the buffer when, in fact, a lot more have been arrived beacuse the creation and buffering of the instance objects is asynchronous.

Can you think of a way to mitigate this problem?

(I'd buffer the Instances in Redis and not in memory, but in that case I'd have some serious serialization problem. Each instance object is quite rich in methods)

Comment: Serialization is easy. You serializer the data, not the prototype. All the methods should live in the prototype

Comment: Yes indeed... I'm going to refactor the way I access and buffer my business objects